# Python concatenating strings - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, string, utf-8, ascii

I want to concatenate two strings like this:

```
requestData = command + ' ' + data
```

"data" in my case holds binary data, that should not be opened - it should just glue it to command. But imho python is attempting to open it and it fails with:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to glue it without opening?

Edit: 
Python 2.7
Also my data is actualy not utf-8 decode might not help - its binary data.

Comment: Which Python version is this? Must be 2.something, but Python 2.7.3 successfully concatenates non-ascii strings: `In [1]: 'привет' + ' ' + 'Veseliq'
Out[1]: '\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 Veseliq'`.

Comment: Its python 2.7, and the data is misc binary data

Comment: Is `command` unicode? If yes, `encode` it first.

Comment: how do you initalize your command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using http://docs.python.org/library/array.html (with 'B') instead of string

Comment: Sure - it appears that you never intended to use the data as a printable string (in which case I would have recommended to change the encoding used from ASCII to a unicode representation). In that case using string makes little sense and can cause unexpected problems. My suggestion was to use a type that properly represents your intent, and then concatenating items of that type (e.g. using http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array.extend), 'B' represents unsigned char, which is equivalent to one byte, which seems to be the proper representation if I understand your needs correctly.