# Anyone know how to fix a unicode error?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I am using Google App Engine for Python, but I get a unicode error is there a way to work around it?
Here is my code:

```
def get(self):
    contents = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Content ORDER BY created DESC")
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(output, 'w') as myzip:
        for content in contents:
            if content.code:
                code=content.code
            else:
                code=content.code2
            myzip.writestr("udacity_code", code)

    self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/zip"
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=test.zip"
    self.response.out.write(output.getvalue())
```

I now get a unicode error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)

I believe it is coming from output.getvalue()... Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If you include the complete stacktrace, we won't have to guess as to where the error occurs - the stacktrace tells you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Areke Ignacio's answer is the fix. For a brief walkthrough here is a post I did recently "Python and Unicode Punjabi" https://www.pippallabs.com/blog/python-and-unicode-panjabi

Comment: where is Ignacio's answer? what am I missing?

Comment: Probably removed by him. That answer is from few years ago. However the blog link should answer any doubt you have in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.
in the end I solved it by changing the call to writestr from

```
myzip.writestr("udacity_code", code)
```

to

```
myzip.writestr("udacity_code", code.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score -1):

From this link:

> [Python UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934184/python-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-ordinal-not-in-r)
>
> However in the meantime your problem is that your templates are ASCII
>   but your data is not (can't tell if it's utf-8 or unicode). Easy
>   solution is to prefix each template string with u to make it Unicode.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this... How would I do that?